# Can't Add JWT_AUTH in setting

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt

I want to set the expiration period for JWT token, so I added this on settings.py

```
JWT_AUTH = {
    'JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(days=30),
}
```

Once I add it on settings, I'm getting this error

```
django.contrib.sites.models.Site doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

What's wrong with 'JWT_AUTH'? These are related parts of settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'corsheaders',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'rest_auth.registration',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_auth',
    'profiles',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
]
# localhost:8000/
SITE_ID = 9
```

Comment: A url is calling a view that is importing the sites framework that isn't loaded yet. Only candidate is corsheaders, but I don't see how that would tie in with adding that JWT_AUTH dict.

Comment: Um.. ok I put corsheaders after 'django.contrib.sites'. But it didn't work either. I think you found what the problem is.

Comment: Did you also follow the [instructions for the authentication backends](https://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently, any unresolved references in settings.py results in Site model errors, not name errors in settings.py.

Though that doesn't happen in stock Django (`python manage.py check`):

> 'foo': datetime.timedelta(days=3),
>
> NameError: name 'datetime' is not defined

DRF does has some settings mangling that may cause this behavior.